# How can I save and open an ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, switch-statement, graphics2d

I'm trying to save an `ArrayList` of `GraphicObjects` to reload it later. The problem is, I can't load the `ArrayList`, I always get an empty `ArrayList` instead of the original `ArrayList`.
There are Objects like `[Line@2f06692f]` in the original `ArrayList`.

Here is the important part of my code:

```
PaintPanel p = new PaintPanel();
...a lot of code...
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ArrayList<GraphObject> savedList= new ArrayList<>();
    switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
        case "Save":
            savedList = p.getGraphicList();
            break;
```

this works and I got the `[Line@2f06692f]` in `savedList`.

However, when I try to load it:

```
        ...some cases...
        case "Load":
            p.setGraphicList(savedList);
            break;
```

This doesn't work somehow, the `savedList` is always empty at this point.

This is my `PaintPanel` class, in which the `graphicList` is what I want to save.

```
public class PaintPanel extends JPanel {

    public ArrayList<GraphObject> graphicList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
```

I have no clue why...

This is my Interface GraphObject:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public interface GraphObject extends Serializable {
    void paint(Graphics2D g2d, boolean tmp);
    void setPaintColor(Color color);
}
```

Comment: For the sake of clarity, are we talking about `com.facebook.model.GraphObject` objects or are they your own custom objects?

Comment: I got my own Interface GraphObject

Comment: does "Save" and "Load" cases belong to the same `switch`? if yes then of course in "Load" case the `savedList` will be initialized but empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell, but it seems to me that your `savedList` is in local scope to the `actionPerformed` method, so it goes out of scope when the method ends and isn't actually saved.

Try making `savedList` a field, perhaps? Hard to give the best recommendation with the amount of code you've provided.

[Read more about this in this Scope tutorial](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem! `savedList` is a field now and global defined, not locally in the `actionPerformed` method.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
savedList = p.getGraphicList();
```

you just copy the reference to exactly the same list. All changes made by PaintPanel later will affect `savedList` variable also. Please try to change it to

```
savedList = new ArrayList<>(p.getGraphicList());
```

Comment: thanks, durron597 solved my problem, but this solved a problem which I would have got later. Thanks! I solved it with: `savedList = new ArrayList<>(p.getGraphicList())`

Comment: yeah, I see now, two separate issues